# how to delete record from a join table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a join table having two record `list_id` and `car_id`. I want to delete a record where `list_id = 5` and `car_id = 7` for example. Here is my code in the controller section:

```ruby
def deletejoin
  @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end
  def destroyjoin
    #  car = Car.find(params[:id])
    #  list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    # car = Car.find(21.to_i)
    # list = List.find(8)
    #  puts car
    #  puts list
     car = Car.find(params[:id])
     @list = car.lists.find(params[:list_id])
     cars_lists.where(car_id: 25).destroy_all
    #  @list.cars.where(:id => params[:id]).destroy_all
    #  @list = @car.cars_lists.find(params[:list_id])
    # @list.destroy
    # car = Car.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Car #{car.name} destoryed successfully"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index', :list_id => @list.id)
  end
```

Comment: car = Car.find(params[:id])
@list = car.lists.find(params[:list_id])
cars_lists.where(car_id: 25).destroy_all
the ids comes correctly but can't delete this specific record, please help me

Comment: please , Improve the code section to get better answers

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot for your help
the following code solved it and it now deleted from the join table only

```
cars = Car.find(params[:id])
 list = cars.lists.find(params[:list_id])
 cars.lists.delete(params[:list_id])
```

Comment: how to find all the lists that is having the same car id in a list

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def delete_join
    car = Car.find(params[:id])
    list = List.find(params[:list_id])
    CarsLists.where(car_id: car.id, list_id: list.id).destroy_all
end
```

This code delete all the records from the join table car_lists by matching car_id and list_id.

Answer (score 0):

First, your current code is displaying two different methods ('deletejoin' and 'destroyjoin'). You only need one method to do this.

Second, you do not specify how the user should be able to destroy the data. Since you use 'params[:id]' and 'params[list_id]' in your code, I assume you'll get the car_id and list_id through a form or through an http url.

- If it the case, referring to 'params[..]' is alright.
- If it is not the case, then you could set two parameters to your 'destroyjoin' method and call the method with the car_id and list_id you want to delete.

That being said, withing you 'destroyjoin' function, some part of your code is ok but another part is wrong. I'll give you the details :

```html
car = Car.find(params[:id])
```

The part of the code above is ok. You'll indeed get the car with the id = params[:id].

```html
 @list = car.lists.find(params[:list_id])
```

This second part of code is wrong. Indeed, when you use 'car.lists', you will get a collection (or an 'array' if you prefer) of all the lists related to a given car. On this collection, you cannot use the ActiveRecord method 'find'. The ActiveRecord 'find' can only be called on a class, such as Car (please note the capital 'C') or such as 'List' (please note the capital 'L').

Instead, you should use the following code to find the list :

```html
list = List.find(params[:list_id])
```

Then, once you get the car to destroy and the list to destroy, you can identify them directly with their id ('list.id' and 'car.id'). Besides, you can look for the instance of your join table to destroy. For this, I assume you also have a model related to your 'cars lists' join table, whose class should be written with capital letters : CarsLists.
Therefore, the code should be :

```html
CarsLists.where(car_id: car.id, list_id: list.id).destroy_all
```

Last, I guess you'll also want to destroy a CarsLists record if either a car or a list are destroyed. If yes, you'll only have to go to your car.rb model and to your list.rb model to write the following :

```html
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carslists, dependent: :destroy
end
                              
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :carslists, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Hello there. Did one of the answers eventually help you? Don't hesitate to upvote or even close your question by ticking the 'check mark'. Thanks.